# IE Error TypeError: Unable to get value of the property 'set': object is null or undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, web, struts2, dojo

I am getting the following error when i run my web application in IE9. The application is using **Struts** and **DOJO UI**.

**Development console is showing:**

```
TypeError: Unable to get value of the property 'set': object is null or undefined
```

This error does not occur in FF or other browsers. I have looked at other solution to this issue and none seems to remedy my problem.

**I have tried** using  tag in the head of my web page:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
```

**The JavaScript which it is failing on:**

```
require(["dojo/on", "dojo/dom", "dojo/_base/lang", "dojo/domReady!", "dojo/query","dijit/registry"],
  function (on, dom, lang, query) {

    $(document).ready(function () { 

      var addButton = dijit.byId('addName');

      if(addButton){
          addButton.on('click', function (evt) {
              evt.preventDefault();
              grid.addRecord('name');

            });       
      }
});
```

Comment: `$(document)` syntax refers to jquery. Are you using Jquery as well. To use `ready()` in dojo, you need to require the dojo ready module like `dojo/ready`. The `dojo/domReady` is different to `dojo/ready`. The `domReady` should be at the end. Also the modules that you are requiring does not match the parameters in the callback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the changes below and you should be good to go.

```
 // Moved dojo/domReady! at the end. Added dojo/ready module.
 require(["dojo/on", "dojo/dom", "dojo/_base/lang", "dojo/ready", "dojo/query","dijit/registry", "dojo/domReady!" ],
  // The callback list below should match the modules in the require statement.
  function (on, dom, lang, ready, query, registry) {

    // $(document) refers to Jquery plugin. Are you using Jquery
    //$(document).ready(function () { 
    ready(function () {    //  using the dojo/ready module.

      // changed dijit to registry
      //var addButton = dijit.byId('addName'); 
      var addButton = registry.byId('addName');

      if(addButton){
          addButton.on('click', function (evt) {
              evt.preventDefault();
              grid.addRecord('name');

            });       
      }
});
```